# Notice undefined variable

Tags: jquery, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)
>   [Notice: Undefined variable but it’s defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022290/notice-undefined-variable-but-its-defined)

when i include the file normal and load the page it works fine but when i load the file in a page using **jquery** it gives this error, i'm using **@include** '...';

index.php load it with no error

> Notice: Undefined variable: name_2 in C:\wamp\www\webex\files\exhange.php on line 42

when i change content and then load it back with jquery it gives the error

```
content.load('files\exchange.php').hide().fadeIn('slow'); hideLoading();
```

the file included contains query to retrieve the info from db, the variable name_2 is the result for that query

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM exchange'); if (!$query)
{ die(); $error = mysql_error(); } 
else { $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $name_2 = $row['name']; }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Can you specify the code present on the line 42?

Comment: `line 42 contains the echo <?php echo name_2; ?>`
before it there's the include of the other file

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
$name_2 = $row[0]['name'];
```

Comment: Why? a) it doesn't solve the problem, b) I think it's wrong!

Comment: Or what is a better solution? Any ideas why it doesn't work properly? Any insight will be highly appreciated. Suggestions/answers are much appreciated: thank yous in advance. Can u please help me out ? How can I solve this??

Answer (score 0):

`$query = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM exchange'); if (!$query) { die(); $error = mysql_error(); } else { $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $name_2 = $row['name']; }`

`$name_2` is ONLY set if the `else` is executed, and since that's inside the { }, it only exists within those {}.

You may want to add `$name_2= ''` before your query. 
(Yes, I've done this myself a few times and wondered why it doesn't work as I expect!)

Comment: Thanks for any help/pointers/advice/guesses! Thank you in meeknes How can I fix this?

Comment: probably need more of your code - I'm pretty sure you need to look at the scope (which pair of {}, essentially, your $name_2 is in, and where you are using it is, in relation - if $name_2 is introduced INSIDE in the level of braces to your use of it, it won't work!)